how take two string input from user
import java.util.Scanner;

public class userInput {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.print("Enter Number = "+ obj.nextInt());
        String name =  obj.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Name = "+ name);
        String stream = obj.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter Stream = "+ stream );
         
    }

}

I am unable to take input for stream variable.
